# How to get row_count for a group in polars?

Tags: python-polars, rust-polars

The usage might seems like the code below

```
out_df = df.select([
    pl.col("*"),
    pl.col("md5").row_count().over("md5").alias("row_count"),
])
print(out_df)
```

The data should be like this:

**before**:

md5

a

a

b

**after**:

md5 row_count

a   1

a   2

b   1

Answer (score 6):

If I think I understand correctly, you want to have a count per seen value in the group.

You can do this:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({"md5": ["a", "a", "b"]})

(df
.with_columns(pl.lit(1).alias("ones"))
.select([
    pl.all().exclude("ones"),
    pl.col("ones").cumsum().over("md5").flatten().alias("row_count")
]))
```

```
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬───────────┐
│ md5 ┆ row_count │
│ --- ┆ ---       │
│ str ┆ i32       │
╞═════╪═══════════╡
│ a   ┆ 1         │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ a   ┆ 2         │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b   ┆ 1         │
└─────┴───────────┘
```

We still have to add a dummy column `"ones"`, because (as of polars==0.10.23` we cannot apply a window function over literals. We will add this functionality.

Comment: It seems like that anticipated functionality is implemented now. How would one use it? I tried ```.with_column(pl.lit(1).cumsum().over("GroupingColumn").alias("RowCount"))``` but that didn't work for me (```exceptions.ComputeError: the length of the window expression did not match that of the group```)

Comment: Clever and simple solution, nice work.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe Im misunderstanding, as your output has both values 1 and 2 for `a`. Assuming you meant `2` for both:

You are very close, Polars has `.count()`:

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({"md5": ["a", "a", "b"]})
out_df = df.select([
    pl.col("*"),
    pl.col("md5").count().over("md5").alias("row_count"),
])
print(out_df)
```

Which prints out this:

```
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬───────────┐
│ md5 ┆ row_count │
│ --- ┆ ---       │
│ str ┆ u32       │
╞═════╪═══════════╡
│ a   ┆ 2         │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ a   ┆ 2         │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b   ┆ 1         │
└─────┴───────────┘
```